# Change Transform.Position.Y

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a GameObject that I wanted to move by `-150` on its Y axis every time the user presses the Down Arrow so it mimics it going down. Here is my code:

```
public GameObject groupHolder;
public float groupHolderY = 100f;
public Vector3 groupPos;

...

if(Input.GetKeyDown("down"))
    {

        //groupHolder.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 20, transform.position.z);

        groupPos = groupHolder.transform.position;
        float newX = groupHolder.transform.position.x;
        float newY = groupHolder.transform.position.y - 150f;
        float newZ = groupHolder.transform.position.z;

        groupHolder.transform.position = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);

    }
```

When I presses the down arrow key, my GameObject disappears off my screen. I checked the inspector and its Y axis is now `19097`. If I try `-1f` it changes the Y axis to `27` and then to `155`.

What is going on? I just wanted to subtract a `150` from its Y axis every time the down key is pressed like:

Y=0 > (Down Key Pressed) > Y=-150 >(Down Key Pressed) > Y=-300 > (Down Key Pressed) > Y=-450

How can I achieve something like this? Thanks!

BTW I'm working on a 2D Game.

Comment: There isnt anything wrong with the code. Perhaps there is something with your scene hierarchy going on? Like you are moving a parent of the gameobject instead of the actual gameojbect? (thus making the child gameobject move way to much since its moving relative to it parent?)

Comment: This is a very good question. Understanding the concepts of coding on a 30-60 fps basis is not intuitive for new coders and i think most people new to Unity would struggle in this manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply by `deltaTime`

This is because if you are checking for a keydown event every frame, running 30-60 frames every second, pressing a key for a second will apply that transformation 30-60 times in a row.

```
public GameObject groupHolder;
public float groupHolderY = 100f;
public Vector3 groupPos;

...

if(Input.GetKeyDown("down"))
{

    //groupHolder.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 20, transform.position.z);

    groupPos = groupHolder.transform.position;
    float newX = groupHolder.transform.position.x;
    float newY = groupHolder.transform.position.y - (150f * Time.deltaTime);
    float newZ = groupHolder.transform.position.z;

    groupHolder.transform.position = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);

}
```

However, the above will make a smooth movement when the key is depressed. If you want one movement per click, you need to create a boolean like so:

```
public GameObject groupHolder;
public float groupHolderY = 100f;
public Vector3 groupPos;
protected bool moved = false;

...

if(Input.GetKeyUp("down"))
    moved = false;

if(Input.GetKeyDown("down") && !moved)
{
    moved = true;
    //groupHolder.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 20, transform.position.z);

    groupPos = groupHolder.transform.position;
    float newX = groupHolder.transform.position.x;
    float newY = groupHolder.transform.position.y - 150f;
    float newZ = groupHolder.transform.position.z;

    groupHolder.transform.position = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);

}
```